# Trying to create a specific array in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say I have posts, and posts are created by many different users.

I'm trying to get an array thats 2D, and shows the sum of the posts created by each user. A final array might look like:

[["Jeff",2],["Mike",10],["Jenny",3]]

etc.

I'm trying to create this in my posts model, so something like:

```
def self.distribution

logic here

end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `count` method in rails.

```
User.count('posts.id', :include => :posts, :group => "users.name")
```

The call returns an ordered hash:

```
#<OrderedHash {"Jeff"=>2, "Mike"=>10, "Jenny"=>1}>
```

You can convert the result to array:

```
User.count('posts.id', :include => :posts, :group => "users.name").to_a
```

The call returns an array:

```
[["Jeff", 2], ["Mike", 10], ["Jenny", 1]]
```

Comment: This seems to be working for me, the only issue now is I'm doing it a little backwards... I'm doing it like this: Post.where(:user_id => @profile.user.id).count('posts.id', :include => :user, :group => "users.email").to_a. Without getting too far into detail, I need that where statement to narrow things down, by post, rather than grabbing all the posts in general. So here is the problem, I store user names in a profile model - linked to the users table (not to the posts table).. Is there a way to get those profile names in this array?

Comment: I thought you wanted list of users, your filter will return the count for a single user.  Other downside of basing the query on `Post`  instead of `User` is you will not get zero count users.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple Rails way to do it:

```
class User
  def self.distribution
    User.
      joins('posts').
      group('users.id').
      select('users.name, count(posts.id) as counter').
      map{ |entry| [entry.name, entry.counter] }
  end
end

User.distribution
=> [["Jeff",2],["Mike",10],["Jenny",3]]
```

Comment: in the view html, the array is rendering the quotes like "&amp;quot;"...I'm using something like this: <%= User.distribution.inspect %>. Any idea how I can make the "'s show up as "?

Comment: Yeah, that's because the string is getting sanitized for HTML output. If you don't want to perform string sanitizing, use raw(User.distribution.inspect) or User.distribution.inspect.html_safe. That said, I would recommend you do sanitize the user names, at least, when you output them.

Comment: Awesome thanks Pan! I have a followup question that I feel like I should post here rather than create a new one.. I only have email addresses stored in the user's table. I do have a profiles table which has the user's name. Is there a way to connect the correct profile and use that for the name in the array?

Comment: Yeah, simply add another joins(:profile) and then update your select to do select('profiles.name, count(posts.id) as counter') instead of selecting name from the user table.

Comment: After everything it works in my local MySQL env, and breaks in Heroku's PG env. sigh

Comment: There's probably something off with the SQL syntax or your database there. Try debugging it, but I would recommend using PG locally if you are going to deploy to a PG environment. MySQL and PG have some differences in syntax.